# How to first expand a string and then evaluate?

Tags: bash

Pretty simple: How do I make this work:

```
export predicate='[[ $LINE $arg ]]'
export LINE=10
export arg='-gt 3'
eval $predicate
```

Produces:

```
eval "${predicate}"
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `$arg'
bash -x -c 'eval "${predicate}"'
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ eval $(echo ${predicate})
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `$arg'
```

Attempt 3:

```
+ eval '[[ $LINE $arg ]]'
bash: eval: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
bash: eval: line 0: syntax error near `$arg'
bash: eval: line 0: `[[ $LINE $arg ]]'
```

It simply isn't expanding those variables.

Comment: Wouldn't `[[ $LINE $predicate ]]` be just enough - do you need to eval?

Comment: [What are you trying to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/130301)

Comment: @liborm - the issue is I know what the variables will be WHEN I need to execute. The variables themselves don't exist until that point. So, I can't do the expansion and that's why I use single quote

Comment: What about a bash function? The variables don't have to exist when you define the function..